# Сохранить автоматически пароль в буфер при закрытии окна

Tags: javascript

Есть готовый код `javascript`, который генерирует случайные пароли. 
Нажал на кнопку "генерировать пароль", открывается окно с паролем в текстовом поле.
Как сделать, чтобы при закрытии окна пароль **автоматически** сохранялся в буфер?

Answer (score 1):

На чистом JavaScript работать с буфером обмена не получится. Тут нужен Flash (например [эта](https://github.com/jonrohan/ZeroClipboard) библиотека). Закрытие окна можно отлавливать по событию [window.onbeforeunload](http://learn.javascript.ru/onload-onerror).